# Cannot load MySql.Data.dll with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, mysql-connector

I would like to create a MySQL database connection using a PowerShell script. I have a problem loading the MySQL.data.dll with my PowerShell script. The MySQL Connector .NET 8.1.0 is installed on the computer. When I run this line manually in Powershell, the MySQL.data.dll load correctly and the  script works perfectly.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector NET 8.1.0\MySql.Data.dll')
```

The same line is at the top of my Skript. When I run the script the line is not executed.
Instead I get the following error message

```
n C:\scripts\api\api.ps1:70 characters:29
+ ... $this.connection = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]::new($ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The type [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection] was not found.
In C:\scripts\api\api.ps1:87 characters:21
+ $command = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand]::new($query, ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The type [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand] was not found.
     + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

I also tried the DLL this way `powershell Add-Type -Path '$path\MySql.Data.dll` to import
That didn't work either.
I have also already tried to copy the MySQL.Data.dll into the same directory as the script and import it from there. That didn't work either.

This is the entire code:

```
# Laden der MySQL-Assembly

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector NET 8.1.0\MySql.Data.dll')

$ConnectorPfad = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll"
Add-Type -Path $ConnectorPfad


class HLdbMySQLConnection {

    [string] $HlDashServerName
    [string] $HlDashDatabaseName
    [string] $HlDashDatabaseUser
    $HlDashDatabasePassword
    [System.Data.IDbConnection]$connection

     
    HLdbMySQLConnection([string] $HlDashServerName,[string] $HlDashDatabaseName, [string] $HlDashDatabaseUser, $HlDashDatabasePassword ){
        
        $this.HlDashServerName       = $HlDashServerName 
        $this.HlDashDatabaseName     = $HlDashDatabaseName
        $this.HlDashDatabaseUser     = $HlDashDatabaseUser
        $this.HlDashDatabasePassword = $HlDashDatabasePassword
        

        $connectionString = "Server=$HlDashServerName;Database=$HlDashDatabaseName;User Id=$HlDashDatabaseUser;Password=$HlDashDatabasePassword;"
        $this.connection = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]::new($connectionString)

        

    }
    
    [void] Open() {
        $this.connection.Open()
        Write-Host "Verbindung hergestellt"
    }

    [void] Close() {
        $this.connection.Close()
            Write-Host "Verbindung geschlossen"
    }

    [System.Data.IDataReader] ExecuteQuery([string]$query) {
        $command = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand]::new($query, $this.connection)
        return $command.ExecuteReader()
        Write-Host "Verbindung hergestellt"
        

    }
}




function HLDashLoadData {
    # Verbindungsdaten
    $HlDashServerName = "localhost"
    $HlDashDatabaseName = "databasename"
    $HlDashDatabaseUser = "username"
    $HlDashDatabasePassword = Get-Content -Raw -Path ".\config.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
    $HlDashDatabasePassword = $HlDashDatabasePassword.Password
    

    # Erstellen einer MySQL-Verbindungsinstanz
    $mysqlConnection = [HLdbMySQLConnection]::new($HlDashServerName, $HlDashDatabaseName, $HlDashDatabaseUser, $HlDashDatabasePassword)

    $mysqlConnection.Open()

    $query = "SELECT * FROM databasename.newsfeed;"

    # Daten abrufen
    $mysqlDataReader = $mysqlConnection.ExecuteQuery($query)

    # While-Schleife zum Durchlaufen der Datensätze und Ausgeben
    while ($mysqlDataReader.Read()) {
        $column1 = $mysqlDataReader["kurznachricht"] # Ersetzen Sie "Spalte1" durch den Namen Ihrer Spalte

       Write-Host "Spalte 1: $column1"
    }

    # Verbindung schließen
    $mysqlConnection.Close()

}
HLDashLoadData
```